# matlab serial/fgets doen't work with non ascii chars

Tags: matlab, serial-port, data-import

executing the script:

```
in = serial('/dev/ttyS0', 'BaudRate', 9600, 'DataBits', 8, ...
    'Parity', 'none', 'StopBits', 1, 'Terminator', 'LF');
fopen(in);
line = fgets(in);
```

and input data 'ñ\n' (hexa C3 B1 0A), `fgets` hangs and timeouts, i,e, doesn't recognize LF.
This only happens when inputting extended non-ascii strings. I'm using Matlab 7.12 R2011a